# Specifying toolset version when building boost 1.55 with MSVC 2015

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, build, visual-studio-2015

I download boost 1.55, extract it, and run the following:

```
> bootstrap.bat
cl : Command line warning D9035 : option 'GZ' has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release
cl : Command line warning D9036 : use 'RTC1' instead of 'GZ'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/MLd'

Bootstrapping is done. To build, run:
...

> b2 --build-type=complete --build-dir=build --toolset=msvc-14.0 stage
```

However, I get the following error:

```
error: msvc initialization: parameter 'version' inconsistent
error: no value was specified in earlier initialization
error: an explicit value is specified now
```

Following the same steps with MSVC 2012, I didn't get that error.

If I do `--toolset=msvc` instead, then it works. However, the generated files have `-vc` instead of `-vc140`, which is what I'd like.

How do I specify the toolset explicitly? Where was it *"specified in earlier initialization"*?

(The reason I want to do this is I am getting a weird linker error later - saying it's looking for some `-vc120` boost library... and I have no idea why. I'm trying to eliminate all the possibilities.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The previously specified version is in `project-config.jam`:

```
using msvc ;
```

Change it to:

```
using msvc : 14.0 ;
```